# Getting 503 errors on an Azure Static Web App

Tags: azure

We have an Azure Static Web App that is returning 503 errors a few times a day. The site is just HTML, there are no Azure Functions being used. One person may be getting a 503 while another person is able to access the site.

Microsoft Support has reviewed the logs for the site and they cannot see any 5xx errors.

We have Cloudflare in front of the site to help with caching. According to Cloudflare support, a 503 indicates a problem with the hosting provider.

Has anyone experienced something similar

Comment: Are you using Free tier? If yes, this might be the issue. It has got a limit of just 60 compute minutes per day. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/azure-subscription-service-limits#app-service-limits

Comment: Thanks @Yogi, I bumped it up to the standard plan, just in case, but we are still getting the issue. We’ve also experienced it on the .AzureStaticApps.net domain, so that rules out Cloudflare as an issue.